# NuGet Package Restore in MonoDevelop on OSX/Linux

Tags: xamarin, nuget, monodevelop

I'm trying to compile a Visual Studio project with NuGet package restore under MonoDevelop but it's not working out of the box.

NuGet should work on Mono and there's even support built into nuget.targets, so what is missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on issue tracked here: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3278

1. You must use xbuild with all projects that should restore packages on build. MonoDevelop->Preferences->Build [image: Enable xbuild in MonoDevelop or Xamarin Studio]
2. Unix filesystems are case-sensitive. This breaks nuget.targets as the casing inside the file is assumed to be all lower case whereas the files added to a solution in the .nuget folder are cased like "NuGet". Either fixup nuget.targets or change the filenames in your solutions .nuget folder to all lower case.
3. RequireRestoreConsent is true by default in nuget.targets. Edit nuget.targets and change it to false.
4. Package restore puts the package folder in a *weird* location, `$(SolutionDir)/ /packages` (yes, theres a single whitespace folder in between). The reason is that there's a trailing whitespace in nuget.targets in after `$(SolutionDir)` in  `<RestoreCommand>$(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)" -source "$(PackageSources)"  $(RequireConsentSwitch) -solutionDir "$(SolutionDir) "</RestoreCommand>`

Comment: Works a treat :) Is there a way to stop it installing packages every build?  Package restore does slow the builds down majorly...

Comment: @Chris: I noticed the same problem but didn't get around to fix it just yet - contributions to this answer are welcome!

Comment: Where does nuget.targets live on OSX?

Comment: The latest version of Nuget (2.7) should fix #3: http://blog.nuget.org/20130814/nuget-2.7-release-candidate.html