# How can I deploy updates to an OpenShift Mono application with Jenkins?

Tags: deployment, jenkins, mono, openshift

I created a mono application on OpenShift using the community cartridge [here](https://github.com/wshearn/openshift-community-cartridge-mono).

Now, I'm reading about how to set up continuous builds via jenkins [here](https://www.openshift.com/developers/jenkins).

The default mono application doesn't seem to come with any of the necessary scripts for building, restoring NuGet packages, etc. Instead, the git repo seems to have the DLL binaries in it, which doesn't seem sustainable.

What's the best approach for deploying mono on open shift?

Answer (score 0):

I will refine this answer when/if I get it working...

Did you start by clicking the "Continuous Integration - Enable Jenkins" link below your cartridge on your OpenShift Applications page?

Once I did this, my `git push` output changed from:

```
remote: CLIENT_MESSAGE: Stopping Apache+mod_mono HTTPD server
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Stopping Postgres cartridge
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit 8da79f2
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 05e8d1d8
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting Postgres cartridge
remote: Postgres started
remote: CLIENT_MESSAGE: Starting Apache+mod_mono HTTPD server
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

To:

```
remote: Executing Jenkins build.
remote:
remote: You can track your build at https://jenkins-[you].rhcloud.com/job/mono-build
remote:
remote: Waiting for build to schedule...........Done
remote: Waiting for job to complete...............Done
remote: SUCCESS
remote: New build has been deployed.
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

But if I remove the `bin` directory from my source code, then the web site no longer works, even though the build "succeeds." So clearly it is only just blindly copying the files out of git.

So next I did a `Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName OpenShift` in the Package Manager console, then right-clicked on the solution and chose "Enable NuGet package restore," and committed/pushed those changes.

In the Jeninks manager I went to Configure the build and added `xbuild OpenShift.sln` after the `gear build` line in the "Execute shell" area.

Now it actually *tries* to do a real build, which fails with the error:

```
+ xbuild OpenShift.sln
XBuild Engine Version 3.0.7.0
Mono, Version 3.0.7.0
Copyright (C) Marek Sieradzki 2005-2008, Novell 2008-2011.

Build started 01/13/2015 20:56:29.
__________________________________________________
/var/lib/openshift/[my ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenShift.sln:  warning : /var/lib/openshift/[my ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenShift.csproj: /var/lib/openshift/[my ID]/mono/mono/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v10.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets: Project file could not be imported, it was being imported by /var/lib/openshift/[my ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenShift.csproj: Access to the path "/var" is denied.
Project "/var/lib/openshift/[my ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenShift.sln" (default target(s)):
    Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
        Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
    Target Build:
/var/lib/openshift/[my ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenShift.csproj: error : /var/lib/openshift/[my ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenShift.csproj: /var/lib/openshift/[my ID]/mono/mono/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v10.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets: Project file could not be imported, it was being imported by /var/lib/openshift/[my ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenShift.csproj: Access to the path "/var" is denied.
    Task "MSBuild" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "Build" in project "/var/lib/openshift/[my ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenShift.sln".-- FAILED
Done building project "/var/lib/openshift/[my ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenShift.sln".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
```

Looks like it might be [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980909/microsoft-webapplication-targets-was-not-found-on-the-build-server-whats-your) so I made the following manual diff to OpenShift.csproj:

```
-   <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
-   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
+   <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

and copied from `Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications` into the above path in my local project.

After committing/pushing that, now I get this new build error:

```
Project "/var/lib/openshift/[my id]/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenShift.sln" (default target(s)):
    Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
        Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
    Target Build:
        Project "/var/lib/openshift/54b5dc8efcf933bb7300001f/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenShift.csproj" (default target(s)):
            Target RestorePackages:
                Executing: mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 "/var/lib/openshift/[my id]/app-root/runtime/repo/.nuget/NuGet.exe" install "/var/lib/openshift/[my id]/app-root/runtime/repo/packages.config" -source ""   -RequireConsent -solutionDir "/var/lib/openshift/[my id]/app-root/runtime/repo/"
                Cannot open assembly '/var/lib/openshift/[my id]/app-root/runtime/repo/.nuget/NuGet.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

Looks like there's a problem running NuGet.exe - Might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16118190/268066)